# Getting specific item in nameless JSON from JSONArray

Tags: java, android, json

plz help me, im trying to fetch a specific item from this JSON:

```
[[["waves","olas",null,null,1]],null,"es",null,null,null,0.54545456,null,[["es"],null,[0.54545456],["es"]]]
```

this is my code:

```
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(data);
        JSONArray jsonArray1 = jsonArray.getJSONArray(0);
        JSONArray jsonArray2 = jsonArray1.getJSONArray(0);
        JSONArray jsonArray3 = jsonArray2.getJSONArray(0);
        data = jsonArray3.getString(0);
```

its very messy but thats the only way i got to having this array alone:

```
["waves","olas",null,null,1]
```

(im trying to get "waves" in a string variable)

as i see from another code its suppose to work but im getting this error:

> org.json.JSONException: Value waves at 0 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Comment: what you want from this json?

Comment: While this JSON string is a valid one, I suggest you start using JSON objects, since that'll make your data more expressive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
String data = "[[[\"waves\",\"olas\",null,null,1]],null,\"es\",null,null,null,0.54545456,null,[[\"es\"],null,[0.54545456],[\"es\"]]]\n";
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(data);
    JSONArray jsonArray1 = jsonArray.getJSONArray(0);
    JSONArray jsonArray2 = jsonArray1.getJSONArray(0);
    System.out.println(jsonArray2.getString(0));
    System.out.println(jsonArray2.getString(1));
```

Comment: im trying to get "waves" in a string variable

Comment: ok this not what i meant but it helped me find the problem, this line:
JSONArray jsonArray3 = jsonArray2.getJSONArray(0);
was unecessery,
tnx bro!